# svg mask rect has no dimension in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg, mask

I animate on hover the opacity of a masked SVG to put a semi transparent layer over an image. It works all fine except with Firefox, where the mask is not showing and the image goes all white. The mask is applied to the image through CSS

```
        <svg id="svg-fade" class="visible-sm-block img-circle" width="200" height="200">
          <defs>
            <mask id="mask2" width="200" height="200" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
              <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" style="stroke:none; fill: #bbbbbb"></rect>
              <rect x="95" y="50" width="10" height="100" style="stroke:none; fill: #000000"></rect>
              <rect x="50" y="95" width="100" height="10" style="stroke:none; fill: #000000"></rect>
            </mask>
          </defs>
          <rect class="target" width="200" height="200" style="stroke:none; fill: rgba(255,255,255,1)"></rect>
        </svg>
```

The live code can be viewed [here](http://filmstelle.vseth.ethz.ch/filmblog).

Is there an attribute missing or why is the mask not showing up in Firefox?

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact that your svg document is not referenced, you should try to add it directly to the element, thanks to its `mask` property or set it in its inline style. Also, `id` properties should be unique in the whole document, here you've got 3*6 differents `#svg-fade` and as much `#mask2`. And finally, FF doesn't like `-` character in svg's `id` property, you should avoid it. That said, I wonder how do the other browsers works well :)

Comment: objectBoundingBox units need to be in the range 0 to 1. A width of 200 is 200 times the size of the object being masked. Perhaps you meant to use userSpaceOnUse.

Comment: @RobertLongson, these properties are not set in the "live code"

Comment: Thank you Kaiido. It was the duplicate ids of the mask and easy to fix.  
@RobertLongson: i removed this proberties.  
I have 3 viewports in place and first had the width and height set through css media queries, which worked fine in chrome but not in firefox. so I had to put in all 3 svg's and make use of the bootstrap helper classes. Do you know any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For any future reference: I found that the id of the mask has to be unique throughout the whole document even when the mask is defined in the very same SVG and you can't use a class instead either.